# In line View SQL

Tags: sql, inline

```
SELECT ddd.invoice_fk,sss.invoice_rid, ddd.inventory_num, sss.billing_account, sss.Invoice_date 
FROM ( SELECT invoice_rid, billing_account, max(invoice_date) as Invoice_date  
FROM im_invoice  
group by invoice_rid, billing_account ) sss, im_invoice_inventory ddd
where ddd.invoice_fk= sss.invoice_rid
and ddd.inventory_num = '1131497271'
```

```
O/P

206973  206973  1131497271  1011964 2010-01-02 00:00:00.000
206974  206974  1131497271  1011964 2009-12-02 00:00:00.000
214493  214493  1131497271  1011964 2010-02-02 00:00:00.000
249202  249202  1131497271  1011964 2010-04-02 00:00:00.000
```

Hi from this Query i am not able to find out lastest date for inventory No's, pleas help me with this.

Here is the table structure:

- One Billing account can have Multiple Invoice num, (in Query invoice_num we dint use,).
- Invoice_rid  and invoice_fk will generate with respect invoice_num.
- One invoice_num can have multiple inventories.
- Inventory_num  & invoice_fk  are available in im_invoice_inventroy table

Here is the invoice data:

```
Ap Extracted    040402634066 
      Claro Argentina 
03/01/2010  03/19/2010  20097727994     CD    $0.00      $3,293.45   $3,293.45       

Ap Extracted    040402719235 
      Claro Argentina 
04/01/2010  04/20/2010  20097727994     CD    $0.00      $1,374.84   $1,374.84       

Ap Extracted    040402804459 
      Claro Argentina 
05/01/2010  05/19/2010  20097727994     CD    $0.00      $1,253.60   $1,253.60       

Ap Extracted    040403143672 
      Claro Argentina 
09/01/2010  09/21/2010  20097727994     CD    $0.00      $1,312.80   $1,312.80       

Ap Extracted    040403060776 
      Claro Argentina 
08/01/2010  08/19/2010  20097727994     CD    $0.00      $1,777.59   $1,777.59       

Ap Extracted    040402976157 
      Claro Argentina 
07/01/2010  07/20/2010  20097727994     CD    $0.00      $1,946.75   $1,946.75       

Ap Extracted    040402890800 
      Claro Argentina 
06/01/2010  06/18/2010  20097727994     CD    $0.00      $1,435.70   $1,435.70       

Ap Extracted    040403563442 
      Claro Argentina 
02/01/2011  02/18/2011  20097727994     CD    $0.00      $1,180.03   $1,180.03       

Ap Extracted    040403488021 
      Claro Argentina 
01/01/2011  01/19/2011  20097727994     CD    $0.00      $1,282.31   $1,282.31       

Ap Extracted    040403406547 
      Claro Argentina 
12/01/2010  12/21/2010  20097727994     CD    $0.00      $1,803.05   $1,803.05       

Ap Extracted    040403650134 
      Claro Argentina 
03/01/2011  03/18/2011  20097727994     CD    $0.00      $1,357.64   $1,357.64
```

and please explain how i can use inline query more effectively in SQL Queries.

In the above query, invoice_fk is foreign key for im_invoice table, and invoice_rid is Primary key for im_invoice table.

Answer (score 0):

This is the SQL you're looking for.

```
SELECT ddd.invoice_fk, 
       sss.invoice_rid, 
       ddd.inventory_num, 
       sss.billing_account, 
       sss.invoice_date 
FROM   (SELECT billing_account, 
               MAX(invoice_date) AS invoice_date 
        FROM   im_invoice 
        GROUP  BY 
                  billing_account) sss
    INNER JOIN im_invoice inv
        ON sss.billing_account = inv.billing_account 
           and sss.invoice_date = = inv.invoice_date 
        INNER JOIN im_invoice_inventory ddd 
    ON ddd.invoice_fk = inv.invoice_rid 
WHERE  
       AND ddd.inventory_num = '1131497271'
```

Basically you need to remove invoice_rid from you subquery. The reason for this is that the  invoice_rid is the primary key so every invoice will be represented in your results.

However you still need the information in invoice which is why you need to add im_invoice back into the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the latest `invoice_date` for every `inventory_num` in every `billing_account`:

```
SELECT
  i.billing_account,
  ii.inventory_num,
  MAX(i.invoice_date) AS latest_invoice_date
FROM im_invoice i
  INNER JOIN im_invoice_inventory ii ON i.invoice_rid = ii.invoice_fk
GROUP BY i.billing_account, ii.inventory_num
```